# How do you harvest honey in Witcher the Wild Hunt?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've noticed small hives of bees but whenever I try to approach to harvest the honey Geralt starts getting attacked by the bees. I tried casting *Quen* and then harvesting but nothing came of it. Does anyone know how you are supposed to harvest the honey?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Use the *Igni* Sign to kill the bees and knock the beehive down.**

Once its on the ground you can harvest it. Figured this out a little bit later, initially could not even attempt this as the beehive I was trying various methods on was near an NPC and the game restricted me from using *Igni*.

Comment: Please feel free to mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Josuha Aslan Smith How can I harvest the fallen down beehive? I don't get the sign for 'take it' (E on PC), just something like a white hand. What command do I have to use to harvest it?

Comment: You have to wait for it to stop burning (which can take 20 actual seconds at times it seems) before the game will let you harvest it, but use use the same general key/button for interaction and looting that you would normally use (such as E on pc).

Comment: You can also use Aard to stop the fire quickly

Answer (score -2):

No one fully answered this.

Knock the hive off the tree
Use Igni to burn the bees flying around
If when you approach it there is the gauntlet instead of the (E) Loot use Igni on it.
Wait for the fire to go out and you should see the (E) Loot

Comment: I think that the accepted answer was sufficient enough.